# How can I change a MySQL Text field so that all values are prefaced by "-"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "foo" with a varchar field "text" where some rows are prefixed with a "-" and others are not.  What's the best way to update rows so that the "text" field begins with a "-" sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE foo SET text = concat('-', text) WHERE substring(text, 1, 1) <> '-'
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE Foo
SET textField = CASE WHEN LEFT(textField,1) = '-' THEN textField 
                     ELSE CONCAT('-', textField) END
```

Comment: By having no "where" clause, does this update every single field (by replacing those who already have a - by themselves) or does it actually skip those who won't be modified through some back-end query optimization?

Comment: @Vache I would imagine it will update all rows, it might be better to use a where statement if we are only updating one field, it might get hairy if we need to update more than one field though.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `foo`
  SET `text` = CONCAT('-', text)
  WHERE SUBSTR(text, 1, 1) <> '-';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE foo
SET `text` = CONCAT('-', `text`)
WHERE `text` NOT LIKE '-%'
```